# Generate XML that uses a default namespace

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml, xml-namespaces

I want to use Python and lxml to generate XML like the following:

```xml
<root xmlns="foo">
  <bar />
</root>
```

However, the following code creates XML that is semantically identical, but uses ugly auto-generated namespace prefixes instead:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.Element('{foo}root')
etree.SubElement(root,'{foo}bar')
print(etree.tostring(root))
#=> b'<ns0:root xmlns:ns0="foo"><ns0:bar/></ns0:root>'
```

How do I get lxml/etree to generate XML using a single default namespace on the root element, with no namespace prefixes on any descendant elements?

Comment: read http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces

Comment: @LutzHorn Perhaps I'm missing a sentence, but that tutorial (which I've read) only describes how to _query_ against a default namespace, not how to get serialization to _emit_ a default namespace.

Comment: Read again :) (or read my answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `nsmap` parameter, which is described on http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces

```
from lxml import etree

nsmap = {None: "foo"}
root = etree.Element('{foo}root', nsmap=nsmap)
etree.SubElement(root,'{foo}bar')
print(etree.tostring(root))
```

Output

```
b'<root xmlns="foo"><bar/></root>'
```

Comment: This works in terms of the printed result, i.e. after serialization. However, is not quite correct. Actually giving the namespace explicitly does not look nice but is correct. For details see discussion here: https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/136

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward approach would be to not use the namespaces as is, but set the `xmlns` attribute explicitly:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element('root')
root.attrib["xmlns"] = "foo"

etree.SubElement(root, 'bar')

print(etree.tostring(root))
```

Prints:

```
<root xmlns="foo"><bar/></root>
```

Comment: I probably won't accept this answer, because it's a dirty hack, but I will almost certainly end up *using* this answer in my code because it's a _delightfully_ dirty hack.